# how to show a label in an aspx page based on a request query string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have to labels on page load. one comes from a query string and one is coded onto the page. as follows

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblMessage.Text = Request.QueryString["message"];
        lblcard.Text = "Transaction made successfully!";
    }
</script>
```

how do i check if lblmessage has a text then it should only display that label and hide the lblcard text,if lblmessage doesnt have a text then it should show the "transaction made " text

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8).

Your code would look something like this:

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = Request.QueryString["message"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblMessage.Text) {
            lblcard.Text = "Transaction made successfully!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblMessage.Text))
{
lblcard.Text = "Transaction made successfully!";
}
```